# Adding my custom PHP Library in include_path

Tags: php, include-path

I want to add my PHP library file to be included in include_path, so that i can access it from anywhere in my application running on that server. I tried adding it as per the syntax for include_path in php.ini But its not working. I tried get_ini("include_path"); and got the value perfectly. But my functions are not inlcuded in my applications.

Answer (score 7):

You can try using

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'your_new_dir_path');
```

Answer (score 2):

The `include_path` directive defines folders where PHP is looking for files that are being included using [`include()` or its siblings](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). The only benefit is that you don't need the whole path (like `include '/path/to/my/include/file.php'`), but the file name only (`include 'file.php'`)